# Updating ListBox.ItemsSource from deserialized XML and refreshing ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

First of all i wanna say hi to everyone because this is my first post here.

This is my first project in WPF and I've got little problems with items in my ListBox - they're not refreshing when I adding them as Listbox.ItemsSource from deserialized XML. I've implemened the INotifyPropertyChanged interface but something is still missing.

Here's the ListBox declaration:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstbRealmlist" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="160" Height="220" Margin="10,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListboxItemStyle}">
                <ListBox.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SunwellLauncher;component/Images/content-bg.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="None" />
                </ListBox.Background>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBA7C0E" Margin="1" CornerRadius="3" >
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Content="{Binding name}" FontSize="16"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding website}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Realmlists and Realm classes:

```
namespace SunwellLauncher
{
[XmlRoot("Realmlists"), Serializable]
public class Realmlists : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Realm> realm;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [XmlElement("Realm")]
    public ObservableCollection<Realm> Realm
    {
        get { return realm; } 
        set 
        {
            realm = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Realm");
        }
    }

    #region Constructors

    public Realmlists()
    {
    }
    public Realmlists(ObservableCollection<Realm> value)
    {
        this.realm = value;
    } 
    #endregion

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}

public class Realm
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("address")]
    public string address { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("website")]
    public string website { get; set; }
}
}
```

and method wich deserialize XML to Realmlists object and fill ListBox:

```
public void ListItemsAddFromXML(XDocument doc)
    {
        XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Realmlists));
        Realmlists realmlists = (Realmlists)reader.Deserialize(doc.CreateReader());
        lstbRealmlist.ItemsSource = realmlists.Realm;
    }
```

On application startup this method fill ListBox from XML file and this working fine but problem is when i try use it to update it - nothing happen. In other window I'm updating that XML file, wait until changes(XMLsave) and run this method again to update Listbox. Method is called from FileSystemWatcher when xml changes is done through delegate.

```
private void CreateWatcher()
    {
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Filter = "Realmlists.xml";
        watcher.Changed += watcher_FileChanged;
        watcher.Path = mw.path;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    void watcher_FileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new MainWindow.ListItemsAdd(mw.ListItemsAddFromXML), doc);

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        watcher.Created -= watcher_FileChanged;
        watcher.Dispose();
    }
```

I also change List to ObservableCollection in Realmlists definition.

Where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the Listbox ItemSource to the Realmlist using a Binding expression in Xaml. Currently you are instantiating the list and setting the ItemSource in code behind.

See also [Binding Declarations Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx)